# Setwise limit of measures on a descending sequence of sets

Tags: measure-theory, double-sequence

This problem is from Royden's *Real Analysis, (4-th e.d.)*, Chapter 18, Problem 66 (pp. 393).

**Problem Statement**

> Let $(X, \mathcal{M})$ be a measurable space and $\{ \nu_n \}$ a sequence of finite measures on $\mathcal{M}$ that converges setwise on $\mathcal{M}$ to $\nu$. Let $\{ E_k \}$ be a descending sequence of measurable sets with empty intersection. Show that for each $\epsilon > 0$, thre is a natural number $K$ for which $\nu _n (E_K) < \epsilon$ for all $n$.

In other words, to show the convergence in $k$ is uniform.

**My attempt**

Since $\nu_n$'s are bounded and $\bigcap _{k = 1} ^\infty E_k = \emptyset$, the continuity of measure implies that
$$
  \lim _{k \to \infty} \nu_n(E_k) = \nu_n \left( \bigcap _{k = 1} ^\infty E_k  \right) = \nu _n (\emptyset) = 0 \quad \text{for all } n.
$$
On the other hand, setwise-convergence of $\nu_n$ implies that
$$
  \lim _{n \to \infty} \nu_n (E_k) = \nu (E_k) \quad \text{for all } k.
$$
So we have
$$
  \begin{matrix}
    \nu_1(E_1) & \nu_2(E_1) & \nu_3(E_1) & \cdots & \to \nu(E_1) \\
    \nu_1(E_2) & \nu_2(E_2) & \nu_3(E_2) & \cdots & \to \nu(E_2) \\
    \nu_1(E_3) & \nu_2(E_3) & \nu_3(E_3) & \cdots & \to \nu(E_3) \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & & \\
    \downarrow & \downarrow & \downarrow & & & \\
    \nu_1(\emptyset) & \nu_2(\emptyset) & \nu_3(\emptyset) & = 0
  \end{matrix}
$$
Moreover, because $\{ E_k \}$ is descending, $\nu_n (E_k) \geq \nu_n(E_{k+1})$, so $\{ \nu(E_k) \}$ is a finite decreasing sequence bounded below by $0$.

This is the most information I can infer from the setting. I tried showing that for every $\epsilon > 0$, there is $K$ and $N$ such that
$$
  n > N \implies \nu_n(E_K) < \epsilon ,
$$
which I do by contradiction. Suppose otherwise, then there is an $\epsilon_0 > 0$, and for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$, a strictly increasing subsequence $\{ n(i, k) \} _{i = 1} ^\infty$ which $\nu_{n(i, k)}(E_k) \geq \epsilon _0$ for all $i$. $\color{red}{\textrm{If one can show that $\nu(E_k) \to 0$}}$, then both $\nu(E_K)$ and $|\nu_{n(i, K)}(E_K) - \nu(E_K)|$ can be bounded by $\epsilon_0 / 2$, arriving at a contradiction and finishing the proof. However, although $\{ \nu(E_k) \}$ is a boudned decreasing sequence, I cannot show and is unsure whether $\nu(E_k)  \to 0$.

Please let me know if there is any idea on this problem. Any help is appreciated.

---

**Editted**

It turns out if $\color{red}{\text{$\nu$ is not finite}}$, the conclusion does not hold. See @copper.hat 's comment below for a counter-example.

Despite this, if we assumed $\nu$ is also finite, it there a way to prove the statement?

Comment: I don't think such an elementary proof is possible. Something like Baire Category Thorem is needed. Unfortunately my copy of Royden has only 15 chapters!

Comment: I still cannot see how to apply the Baire Category Theorem or other metric-space related theorems, since we are only given a measurable space and the setwise convergence condition...

Comment: I am probably missing something, but if you take $\nu_n(E) = m(E \cap [0,n])$ ($m$ the Lebesgue measure) and $E_k = [k, \infty)$, then $\nu_n \to m$ setwise and $\cap_k E_k$ is empty, but $\nu_n(E_k) = n-k$ for $n \ge k$.

Comment: Don't wish to infringe any legal rights, but https://s2pnd-matematika.fkip.unpatti.ac.id/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Real-Analysis-4th-Ed-Royden.pdf

Comment: @copper.hat The conclusion is true if $\nu$ is also assumed to be finite. Perhaps, OP did not copy the statement correctly.

Comment: I checked the book again, and I saw no assumption that $\nu$ is finite. I think @copper.hat ‘s comment provides a valid counter-example if $\nu$ is infinite. Despite this, is there a way to prove this if $\nu$ is assumed finite?